# Firebird equivalent

Tags: macos, software-rec, osx-leopard, gtd

I was looking for a GTD App with priorities and deadlines for mac os x and found Firebird, but only works on Snow Leopard and I have Leopard and can not update (computer at work). There is some equivalente program for GTD With priorites and deadlines?

Comment: Interested in GTD? Join [Personal Productivity and Organization](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity-and-organization-gtd-covey-etc), we are looking for users & experts... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Mac user, but the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/install210.html#install2-macosx) does say that Firebird 2 is supported on Leopard.

If your problem is 64-bit, see this article : [64bit Firebird for MacOS 10.5 (Leopard)](http://paulbeachsblog.blogspot.com/2008/01/64bit-firebird-for-macos-105-leopard.html).

Answer (score 0):

GTD (at least in my novice opinion) is more than priorities and deadlines -- you get that integrated in iCal tasks.

[Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) and [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnifocus/) are popular, commercial GTD-ish apps for Mac OS X.